# Why does $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} = \frac{1}{x}(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2})^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ when $x \gg a$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My textbook lists this result but I don't understand how it was obtained. If I was solving the problem myself I would say that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2}} = \frac{1}{x}$ when $x \gg a$ because the $a^2$ term is practically negligible.

Comment: In the title only the $\frac{1}{x}$ was factored out, this is true for all $x\neq 0$

Comment: @DominicMichaelis:  $x>0$, otherwise the terms have different signs.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that in your case $x$ is positive. Then just factor the $x$ out of the root:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} = \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+a^2/x^ 2}} = \frac{1}{x}\left(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}.$$

If $x$ is much bigger than $a$, then the factor to the right is approximately $(1 + \epsilon)^{-1/2} \approx 1 - \frac 12 \epsilon$ by a Taylor first order approximation.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the binomial theorem when $\frac ax << 1$ in the following way:
$$\frac1{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}} = \frac1x \left(1+ \frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)^{-1/2} = \frac1x\left(1- \frac12 \frac{a^2}{x^2} + \cdots\right) $$

Answer (score 1):

That's not what the equals sign means! For any $a \neq 0$, $(1+a^2/x^2) \neq 1$, so
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} = \frac{1}{x}\left( 1+\frac{a^2}{x^2} \right)^{-1/2} \neq \frac{1}{x}. $$
Actually, all the book has assumed is that $x>0$, so that $\sqrt{x^2}=x$. Then
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} = (x^2+a^2)^{-1/2} = \left( x^2 \left( 1+ \frac{a^2}{x^2} \right) \right)^{-1/2} = \frac{1}{x} \left(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)^{-1/2}. $$

What you are trying to express is written mathematically as
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} \sim \frac{1}{x} \quad \text{as } x \to \infty. $$
Here, the symbol $\sim$, pronounced "is asymptotically equal to" is defined as:
$$ f(x) \sim g(x) \text{ as } x \to x_0 \iff \lim_{x \to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \to 1. $$